# How to reload a multimethod in Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure

I am writing a multimethod in the REPL, functions can be redefined just fine, but if I redefine the dispatch function of a multi method it seems not to use the newly refined function:

```
;; simple fn to resolve defmethod to call, hardcoded to :do-it
(defn resolve-it [] :do-it)
(resolve-it) ;; :do-it, as expected

(defmulti do-something resolve-it)

(defmethod do-something :do-it [] (println "do-it"))
(defmethod do-something :oh-no [] (println "oh-no"))

(do-something) ;; "do-it", as expected

;; now change resolve-it
(defn resolve-it [] :oh-no)
(resolve-it) ;; :oh-no, as expected

(do-something) ;; "do-it", not as expected

(do-something) ;; "do-it", not expected
```

How do I get the mult imethod to reflect changes to the dispatch function, `resolve-it`?

Answer (score 13):

There is a simple technique that allows re-defining the dispatch function of the multimethod. The idea is to pass the var that holds the dispatch function to `defmulti`, not the function itself. Note the `#'resolve-it` in `defmulti` instead of just `resolve-it`. Thus the var is de-referenced at runtime, not just at compile time.

```
(defn resolve-it [] :do-it)
(resolve-it) ;; :do-it, as expected

(defmulti do-something #'resolve-it)

(defmethod do-something :do-it [] (println "do-it"))
(defmethod do-something :oh-no [] (println "oh-no"))

(do-something) ;; "do-it", as expected

;; now change resolve-it
(defn resolve-it [] :oh-no)
(resolve-it) ;; :oh-no, as expected

(do-something) ;; "oh-no", expected!!
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [clojuredocs example](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defmulti#example-55d9e498e4b0831e02cddf1b) `defmulti` won't allow you to redefine it. You will have to unmap `do-something` from the namespace(`ns`):

`(ns-unmap *ns* 'do-something)`

and reassign it, as you did before:

```
(defmulti do-something resolve-it)
(defmethod do-something :do-it [] (println "do-it"))
(defmethod do-something :oh-no [] (println "oh-no"))
```

Comment: This works, I can put the `ns-unmap` at the top of the file, for experimentation purposes, and when I send the file to the nREPL the changes are as expected.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `defmulti` is caching the dispatch function.  Here is a modified version of your code that illustrates the problem:

```
;; simple fn to resolve defmethod to call, hardcoded to :do-it
(defn who-is-it [person] (:name person))
(spyx (who-is-it {:name :joe}))

(defmulti  do-something who-is-it)
(defmethod do-something :homer [person] :doh)
(defmethod do-something :bill  [person] :oh-no)
(defmethod do-something :ted  [person] :excellent)

(spyx (do-something {:name :homer}))
(spyx (do-something {:name :bill}))

;; now change who-is-it
(defn who-is-it [arg] :ted)
(spyx (who-is-it :wilma)) ;; expected result = :excellent
(spyx (do-something {:name :betty}))
```

with results:

```
:reloading (tst.clj.core)
(who-is-it {:name :joe}) => :joe
(do-something {:name :homer}) => :doh
(do-something {:name :bill}) => :oh-no
(who-is-it :wilma) => :ted
:error-while-loading tst.clj.core

Error refreshing environment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'do-something' for dispatch value: :betty, compiling:(tst/clj/core.clj:22:27)
```

It looks like you may need to reinitialize the REPL to redefine the dispatch fn.  Even repeating everything did not overwrite `do-something` for me:

```
(defmulti  do-something who-is-it)
(defmethod do-something :homer [person] :doh)
(defmethod do-something :bill  [person] :oh-no)
(defmethod do-something :ted  [person] :excellent)

(spyx (do-something {:name :betty}))   ;=> ***same error ***
Error refreshing environment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'do-something' for dispatch value: :betty, compiling:(tst/clj/core.clj:30:1)
```

Here with a new session we see the expected behavior:

```
;; simple fn to resolve defmethod to call, hardcoded to :do-it
(defn who-is-it [person] (:name person))
(spyx (who-is-it {:name :joe}))

;; now change who-is-it
(defn who-is-it [arg] :ted)
(spyx (who-is-it :wilma)) ;; expected result = :ted
; (spyx (do-something {:name :betty}))

(defmulti  do-something who-is-it)
(defmethod do-something :homer [person] :doh)
(defmethod do-something :bill  [person] :oh-no)
(defmethod do-something :ted  [person] :excellent)

(dotest
  (spyx (do-something {:name :betty})))

(do-something {:name :betty}) => :excellent  ; *** as expected ***
```

## Update

I tried the `ns-unmap` technique Rumid described and it works also. I noticed you have to reissue ***both*** the `defmulti` ***and*** all of the `defmethod` statements:

```
(ns-unmap *ns* 'do-something)    ; be sure to remember the quote
(defmulti  do-something who-is-it)
(defmethod do-something :homer [person] :doh)
(defmethod do-something :bill  [person] :oh-no)
(defmethod do-something :ted  [person] :excellent)

(dotest
  (newline)
  (spyx (do-something {:name :betty}))) ;=> :excellent
```

Comment: where is spyx from?

Comment: It's from tupelo: https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Another little trick is to def the var to nil first:

```
(defmulti hello #(do (println "Hello") %))
(defmethod hello :world ([_] (println "World!")))

;> (hello :world)
Hello
World!

(def hello nil) ;; Eval this and you can now redef the defmulti
(defmulti hello #(do (println "Changed!") %))
(defmethod hello :world ([_] (println "World!")))

;> (hello :world)
Changed!
World!
```

Be warned there's a trade-off, if you redef the defmulti it removes the defmethods and you need to redef those as well, which is why defmulti is normally caching and does not let you redef it.